# How to scroll page using css class in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to a add class based on device width in if statement. Is it possible?? I am trying this below code but it show error.
Thanks.

`

```
<style>
.red{ color:red;}

@media(min-width: 480px){
    .scroll_value{ top:200px;}
}

@media(min-width: 992px){
    .scroll_value{ top:500px;}
}
</style>

<script> 
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > ('scroll_value') {
        $('#ids').addClass('red'); 
    } else {
        $('#ids').removeClass('red');
    }
}); 
</script>

<div id="ids"> red</div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($(document).scrollTop() > ('scroll_value') {...
```

should be:

```
 if($(document).scrollTop() > value) {...
```

Comment: but, i want to scroll page based on css value.

Comment: @user3523031 So get css value with jquery .css()

Comment: but how can i achieves this on @media query.